# SQL Server Regex search

Tags: sql-server-2008

My requirement is to search a column value like "starts with C and followed by four consecutive digits" using SQL Server `regex`.

Say my table contains following data:

```
Id    Num
---   ----
1     C1234
2     C23215
3     C4321 XYZ
4     Z1234
5     C4521
```

and query will only get results  C1234 and C4521.

I have tried this `select * from Mytable where Num like 'c[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`  but not getting desired result.

Please help me.

Comment: sql server does not support regex. it's patindex.

Comment: Ok, so how to achieve using  `patindex`?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Id INT, Num VARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'C1234' ),
        ( 2, 'C23215' ),
        ( 3, 'C4321 XYZ' ),
        ( 4, 'Z1234' ),
        ( 5, 'C4521' )

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
WHERE   Num LIKE 'c[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Output:

```
Id  Num
1   C1234
5   C4521
```

The problem is probably you are using case sensitive collation or `c` is from another language alphabet or you have some invisible characters in strings. Try to change to capital `C` and `select len(Num)` to see if the length of `C1234` is really 5.

Comment: Did as u said but getting no result.

Comment: Probably you have invisible characters. See edited answer.

Comment: I don't think so. Not getting any result, zero row returned.